# How to drag a <line> inside <rect> in Javascript or JqueryUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have `rect` and `line` elements inside SVG. I want to drag a line horizontally inside the `rect` using jQueryUI. I am trying to follow [this](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) example.

This is my SVG

```
 <svg width="400" height="110" >
   <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="containment-wrapper"/>
   <line x1="150" id="draggable" y1="0" x2="150" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
 </svg>
```

code

```
 $(function() {
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", 
   scroll: false });
 });
```

But it is not working as expected, the line doesn't move at all.

**Update**

I tried with dynamic line element,its not working as expected.

SVG:

```
<g id="grp">
<rect x="488.5" y="380.3" 
   width="76.7" height="38.5" id="rct1" style="pointer- 
    events:inherit">
</rect>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 515.272 
   402.9645)" id="txt1" style="pointer- 
   events:inherit">Check</text>
</g>
```

Code:

```
Bbox = document.getElementById(rct1).getBBox();

line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
line.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "line_1");
line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", Bbox.x + Bbox.width / 2);
line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", Bbox.x + Bbox.width / 2);
line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", Bbox.y);
line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", Bbox.y2);
line.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
line.setAttributeNS(null, "fill-opacity", "1");
line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "red");
line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "2");
line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-opacity", "1");
line.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "pointer-events: inherit");

document.getElementById(grp).appendChild(line);
$("#grp").draggable("disable");
$("#rct1").draggable("disable");

$("#line_1").draggable({
stack: "#line_1"
drag: function (event, ui) {
var newPos = (ui.position.left > Bbox.x) ? Bbox.x + 1 : ui.position.left;
event.target.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", newPos);
event.target.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", newPos);
 }
 });
```

I disable g and rect but then to its draggable, i need it to be disabled. And line gets dragged into right corner.I passed x of rect as newpos.
Also is there a way to keep line as selected by default?

Answer (score 2):

You may simply update the [x1 and x2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line) attributes of your line on [drag event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag):

```js
$("#draggable1").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var newPos = (ui.position.left > 300) ? 300 : ui.position.left;
        event.target.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", newPos);
        event.target.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", newPos);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="containment-wrapper"/>
    <line x1="150" id="draggable1" y1="0" x2="150" y2="100"
          style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, But it isnot  working properly when the line is created dynamically please check i have updated question.